# Elegant way of reconnecting loop with boost::asio?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, tcp, asio

I am trying to write a very elegant way of handling a reconnect loop with boost async_connect(...). The problem is, I don't see a way how I could elegantly solve the following problem:

I have a TCP client that should try to connect asynchronously to a server, if the connection fails because the server is offline or any other error occurs, wait a given amount of time and try to reconnect. There are multiple things to take into consideration here:

- Avoidance of global variables if possible
- It has to be async connect

A very basic client is instantiated like so:

```
tcpclient::tcpclient(std::string host, int port) : _endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(host), port), _socket(_ios) {
    logger::log_info("Initiating client ...");
}
```

Attempt to connect to the server:

```
void tcpclient::start() {

    bool is_connected = false;

    while (!is_connected) {
        _socket.async_connect(_endpoint, connect_handler);
        _ios.run();
    }

    // read write data (?)

}
```

The handler:

```
void tcpclient::connect_handler(const boost::system::error_code &error) {

    if(error){
        // trigger disconnect (?)
        logger::log_error(error.message());
        return;
    }

    // Connection is established at this point
    // Update timer state and start authentication on server ?

    logger::log_info("Connected?");

}
```

How can I properly start reconnecting everytime the connection fails (or is dropped)? Since the handler is static I can not modify a class attribute that indicates the connection status? I want to avoid using hacky global variable workarounds.
How can I solve this issue in a proper way?

My attempt would be something like this:

**tcpclient.h**

```
enum ConnectionStatus{
    NOT_CONNECTED,
    CONNECTED
};


class tcpclient {

public:

    tcpclient(std::string host, int port);

    void start();

private:

    ConnectionStatus _status = NOT_CONNECTED;

    void connect_handler(const boost::system::error_code& error);

    boost::asio::io_service _ios;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint _endpoint;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket _socket;

};
```

**tcpclient.cpp**

```
#include "tcpclient.h"
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include "../utils/logger.h"

tcpclient::tcpclient(std::string host, int port) : _endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(host), port),
                                                   _socket(_ios) {
    logger::log_info("Initiating client ...");
    logger::log_info("Server endpoint: " + _endpoint.address().to_string());
}


void tcpclient::connect_handler(const boost::system::error_code &error) {

    if(!error){
        _status = CONNECTED;
        logger::log_info("Connected.");
    }
    else{
        _status = NOT_CONNECTED;
        logger::log_info("Failed to connect");
        _socket.close();
    }

}

void tcpclient::start() {

    while (_status == NOT_CONNECTED) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));
        _socket.close();
        _socket.async_connect(_endpoint, std::bind(&tcpclient::connect_handler, this, std::placeholders::_1));
        _ios.run();
    }
}
```

The problem is that the reconnect is not working properly and the application seems to freeze for some reason? Aside from that reconnecting also seems problematic once a connection was established and is then dropped (e.g. due to the server crashing/closing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));` will freeze program for 2 seconds. What can you do here is to launch async timer when connection attempt fails:

```
::boost::asio::steady_timer m_timer{_ios, boost::asio::chrono::seconds{2}};

void tcpclient::connect_handler(const boost::system::error_code &error)
{
    if(!error)
    { 
        _status = CONNECTED;
        logger::log_info("Connected.");
    }
    else
    {
        _status = NOT_CONNECTED;
        logger::log_info("Failed to connect");
       _socket.close();
       m_timer.expires_from_now(boost::asio::chrono::seconds{2});
       m_timer.async_wait(std::bind(&tcpclient::on_ready_to_reconnect, this, std::placeholders::_1));
    }
}

void tcpclient::on_ready_to_reconnect(const boost::system::error_code &error)
{
    try_connect();
}

void tcpclient::try_connect()
{
    m_socket.async_connect(_endpoint, std::bind(&tcpclient::connect_handler, this, std::placeholders::_1));
}

void tcpclient::start()
{
    try_connect();
    _ios.run();
}
```

There is also no need for `while (_status == NOT_CONNECTED)` loop, because io service will be busy and `_ios.run();` won't return until connection is established.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, helps a ton!! I have a question regarding your example. `::boost::asio::steady_timer m_timer{m::boost::asio::chrono::seconds{2}};` Where does the `m` come from? Am I missing some includes? I tried removing it but then I am prompted with no matching constructor? Also I would put this variable in the headerfile as private variable, right? Instead of a global variable.

Comment: @Kyu96 That m was just a random typo. timer also takes io service as a first parameter.

Comment: I see. Big thanks for your fast reply! However there are still two things that concern me:
1) While trying to connect it waits a while for the first attempt but after that it is spamming Failed to connect in the console without any pause? It seems to ignore the 2 seconds of the timer, except for the very first attempt.
2) Right now the program exits once connected. But what if the connection is established and then dropped at random. Will this also trigger the reconnect routine?

Comment: @Kyu96 1) Oh, right, after timer callback is invoked timer will be in expired state so it should be reset prior to calling `async_wait`. 2) If program gets disconnected at some point then connection should be manually reestablished (probably by invoking `try_connect` somewhere).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! A few more things I'd like to ask: 
I want to implement a proper base to send and receive custom data packets.
1) Would it make sense to add two seperate handlers for reading and writing, one for the header one for the body?
2) How can I ensure that I can receive data while I also send data without causing any conflicts?

Comment: 3) Since the data being sent and reived should follow a specific format should I add handlers for both receiving header & body and sending header and body?
4) How would I sent such a custom data packet? A structure? Does boost provide some serializer or something similar?
Maybe you give me a very basic example? I accepted your answer by the way, since the main question has been answered.

Comment: @Kyu96 It would be a better idea to create a separate topics for these questions.

Comment: Fair enough, I created a new topic for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55676585/async-sending-and-receiving-custom-data-packets-with-boost